# Jersey web service, keep request count

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

i've a web service like this in a Jersey Java app:

```
   @Singleton
   @Path("/root")
   public class MyWebService() {

    private int count;

    public MyWebService() {
        count=0;
    }

    @Path("/perf/request")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getCount() {
        String out = "";
        count++;
        out = "Count is: " + out; 
        return out;
    }
   }
```

Due to the Jersey lifecycle, the class is re-instantiated every time a service is called (in spite of the "@Singleton" annotation) and then every time the count is equal to zero.
Is there a way to make this class/field static so the "count" field will not be reset?

Comment: Save your count in a database or txt file stored on the server...That way it won't be reset if you redeploy your application.  You could create another class and make a static variable to store the value but I would recommend using a database or txt file.

Comment: Can you show you're imports. You tagged java-ee. I'm wondering if maybe you're using `@javax.ejb.Singleton`.

Comment: at brso05: hi, at the moment i can't use persistence at the moment (yes, stupid requirements). Also, i already tried with static variable in another class, but it doesn't work.
at peeskillet: yes, i'm usign @javax.ejb.Singleton. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, use `@javax.inject.Singleton`

Comment: Keep in mind thread safety when using stateful resources. For this particular use case, you can use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), and use its `incrementAndGet()`.

Answer (score 1):

That should totally work!  According to the documentation:

> In this scope there is only one instance per jax-rs application.
>   Singleton resource can be either annotated with @Singleton and its
>   class can be registered using the instance of Application. You can
>   also create singletons by registering singleton instances into
>   Application.

Did you register the class with the application?

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    /*Register JAX-RS application components.*/
    public MyApplication () {
        register(MyWebService.class);
    }
}
```

Also you may be importing the wrong annotation type.